# How to fetch single record from Data store using Objectifyby Key.?

Tags: google-app-engine, crud, objectify

I need to fetch the single object from the data store which I have inserted using Objectify.?

Answer (score 0):

This is covered in detail in the documentation:

https://github.com/objectify/objectify/wiki/BasicOperations